# ASP code read incomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

My asp code is not read completely and it doesn't allow me to make it work.

I am totally new to ASP, but I searched a lot of sources for the task I need: **to get the file names from a server directory**

I call `.asp` file with an XMLHttpRequest the following way:

```
function readDir() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
    xhttp.open('get', 'loader/asp/getFiles.asp', true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

and the *getFiles.asp* contains simple output:

```
<%
    Response.Write "First statement"
    Response.Write "Second statement"
%>
```

As a response from the server i get the [this](https://ibb.co/muKakT) content, instead of the result or at least the full source code.

Can somebody give an advice regarding this?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using classic ASP (ie. VBScript) or ASP.Net? I ask as the file extension is `.asp`, and the use of `Response.Write` is rather archaic. If you're using the former I'd suggest learning something else as it's incredibly outdated.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I use classic ASP, because I am new and don't really know what method should I better use to read the directory from the server.

Comment: Classic ASP's last update was nearly 18 years ago. It's not worth learning, unless you need to maintain a legacy system. I would strongly suggest you look in to ASP.Net with C# instead, as it's far more current. ASP.Net MVC would also be very worthwhile. There are already thousands of beginner tutorials for this if you take the time to search.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks a lot for advice. Will try it now.

Comment: What do you get when you view the file directly on the server? (IE via the url `http://yourdomain/loader/asp/getFiles.asp`  What you should see is "First StatementSecond Statement"  If you just get source code or a 404 then you haven't configured IIS to serve classic asp, it isn't enabled by default.